# Can I award a bounty to somebody who solved my problem but did not answer my question?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/q/1687387/1106777) a week ago, asking what I thought was a bizarre problem (but turns out it's not). Two days and no answer so far, I decided to start a 50 rep bounty in hope of seeking answer, as I was desperate enough.

Right after that, the question seeing some comment from user here— one user points out a hint that exactly help answer my question. Then I encourage him to post an answer so I can award the bounty to him, as I think he deserve it fully.

He refused my request, saying he "feels weird" earning 50 point just for a small tip, he then told me to post an answer— which I did.

Now the question is pretty much solved and I don't need anymore answer, though there was one answer pointing to fail2ban configuration, I already checked onto it and did not find something unusual.

I know I won't get the 50 rep back, so can I just award the bounty to him? I don't want my 50 rep reduction to be wasteful.

Comment: You can award your bounty to any eligible answer you want for any reason you want and are not required to justify the reason for doing so. You cannot award a bounty to a comment, a comment isn’t an answer, commentary really should be flagged for deletion. Sounds like the user didn’t submit an answer and thus is ineligible to earn the bounty. If you submitted a bounty it would automatically be awarded to the other answer to your question, even if you don’t select it, after the bounty period expires. Bounties once started cannot be refunded. Your bounty was awarded to the only eligible bounty.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Bounties are (just like upvotes) awarded to an *answer*, not a *user*. Think of them as advertisements (which afterwards function to indicate the quality of a post), not as gifts. The user who solved your problem has 55k reputation and all the privileges he can get, he doesn't have any need for 50 more points.

For more information, see the FAQ [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.